# How To Change Google earth engine Base Map Language

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api, basemap, internationalization

Google Earth Engine docs have an [Article](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/customizing-base-map-styles) on how to Change the base map attributes

Yet not a word about changing the language of this base map.

Is there a way with the Maps API ?